# Fix for the "The following theme is missing from the file system" error in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I keep getting this same error from bugsnag for my site, and I'm unsure how to fix it/why it's popping up in the first place.

```
User Warning · The following theme is missing from the file system: <em class="placeholder">Theme_Name</em>. For information about how to fix this, see <a href="https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215">the documentation page</a>.
```

The theme that it claims it is missing is the only theme I have for the site and is the one it is currently using. Besides overloading my bugsnag reporting, it's not causing any issues. Is there a way to resolve this? I checked the documentation page and all the articles I found only refer to modules.

Comment: check path into system table , maybe you moved it after enabled it so path is old into systeme table . You can also uninstall & install your theme

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the there is an old reference of `Theme_Name` in the `systems` table of your database.

You can look for the references that your Drupal instance is checking against by running this query:

```sql
SELECT name, status, filename FROM system WHERE type = 'theme' AND name = 'Theme_Name';
```

Find the reference that doesn't look quite right, preferably by the `name` of "Theme_Name", and delete it.

```sql
DELETE FROM system WHERE type = 'theme' AND name = 'Theme_Name' AND status = 0 AND filename = 'path/to/Theme_Name.info' LIMIT 1;
```

Once deleted, flush your Drupal caches.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is embarrassing. The source of the problem was that I was adding an image using:

```
src="<?= drupal_get_path('theme','Theme_Name'); ?>/sites/all/themes/theme_name/img/image.png">
```

The first problem is that the theme name I was calling was using capitals when the actual theme was all in lower case. But to actually resolve the problem I changed the image call to:

```
src="<?= drupal_get_path('theme',$GLOBALS['theme']); ?>/img/image.png">
```

Unsure if this turns out to be the same problem others have had, but that's what fixed it for me. If you're getting this error I'd suggest double checking how your src's are being called. Thanks to everyone that answered/responded!